# Sample size for segmentation validation

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sample-size, validation

I've created a automatic algorithm liver segmentation and the next step is the method validation. I have 16 exams with a mean of 40 slices each and my doubt now is how many of these slices would have a technician to hand segment to compare with my algorithm.

I've read about `Hypotesis test` but I can't figure out how to calculate its variables,

here's the link from the source of the test.

http://circ.ahajournals.org/content/114/10/1078.full#disp-formula-6

here's the equation,

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that author currently asks not about how to compare, but how many test observations are needed to do the comparison (possibly to show that the algorithm is no worse as manual segmentation by technician). The answer is "The more is always better". However, it is possible to construct the hypothesis "The difference between two methods is no more than some fixed value". The difference can be measured as the total area of wrong segmentation. Then the sample size $n=(\delta/d)^2$, where $\delta$ is taken from the [table](http://www.unt.edu/rss/class/Jon/ISSS_SC/Module008/delta/) (considering significance level and desired power of test), and $d=(\bar X-\mu)/S$, with $\mu$ - the desired fixed value of difference and S - sample standard deviation. Note that in this case you are working with one-tailed one-sample t-test.
[Here is good introduction to sample size calculations](http://www.unt.edu/rss/class/Jon/ISSS_SC/Module008/isss_m8_introttests/node2.html).

P.S. Have you any relationship to [this article](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1204/1204.1634.pdf)? If no, it'll be interesting for you.

Comment: How can I choose the δ?

Comment: You should predefine significance $\alpha$ and power (1-$\beta$) of test. Usually $\alpha$ is 0.05 and power is taken to be 0.8. If we look at the column that corressponds to alpha=0.05(one-tailed), and search the 0.8 in that column. The $\delta$ we are looking is in the same row where we have found 0.8 . For this example it is 2.50

Comment: I understand that, but the n calculated would be the total number os slices or exams?

Comment: It depends what you treat as independent observation. If you'll treat each slice as independent observation then it is number of slices. If you want to sum up all slices 'differences' from single exam then it will be the number of exams. The first variant is appropriate when all slices are near equally hard to recognize and between-exams variability is neglected (we make an assumption that all exams produce slices of equal quality). In other case summation of slices is preferred (though require much more data).

Answer (score 5):

I understand that you want to compare your automatic and manual segmentation methods. I don't know much about liver segmentation, so I don't know exactly what you will be comparing between the automatic and manual methods. I assume that you have some number that each of the segmentation methods produces for each case.

Use the "paired tests" formula in the reference you cite instead of the formula for the one-sample test you quote in your question. (It's like your formula, but with "d" in the numerator.) Calculate the difference between the automatic and manual methods for each case. Calculate the mean and standard deviation of those differences. The mean difference is the "d", the standard deviation of the differences is "s", and "n" is the number of cases. The t-value will tell you whether there is a significant difference between the two methods; the "degrees of freedom" in the table of t values for significance testing is one less than the number of cases you compare.

How many cases you have to compare depends on how big a difference you want to be able to detect, and how variable you expect the differences between the methods to be. If you have estimates of these, then you can use standard power analysis formulas to determine how many cases to examine. My guess is that you will be best off if you compare all 16 available cases, and use your results on those to guide your future choice of method.

Also, the differences between the methods may come from errors in either of the methods. If there is a significant difference between the two methods, look carefully into why they differ; manual methods aren't necessarily the most accurate.

Comment: Thank you for your time, in the liver segmentation we get a contour, which will be compared with the contour from the hand segmentation. I have 16 exams with 40 slices, so what I want to determine is the number of slices per exam and not how many exams. I'll use all of the exams, I just don't know how many slices. I don't have an estimation before the segmentation of both manual and automatic methods.

Comment: If you are trying to estimate the total liver volume from contours of the liver on slices taken throughout its extent, use the number of slices that you would normally use to estimate the volume by the manual method, and compare volumes. If you mainly care about contours from individual slices as independent observations, choose the number of slices based on the power calculations recommended by @O_Devinyak. You should, however, examine whether your method works as well for slices through the middle of the liver as it does for slices near the tip.